# Porting One Line Of Code

Tags: python, objective-c, ios

Can anybody figure out how the python code below works and give me a possible way to port it to Objective-C (iOS) to work in my own project?

`month_id = calendar.timegm(datetime(year, month, 1, hour, 0, 0).timetuple()) * 1000`

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calendar.timegm converts the given time to time in seconds since epoch of 1970. More information at http://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html?highlight=calendar.timegm#calendar.timegm

Comment: I feel pretty stupid that I couldn't have figured that one out on my own haha. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

open a python interpreter, then enter this:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> from datetime import datetime
```

then input your line of code, and you should be able to get a pretty good idea.